# how to force sign on power bi visual card?

Tags: powerbi

I'm looking for a solution that shows me on a card a percent number with sign.
For example, if I have 10% groxth, I would like to see in the card: +10%

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a better solution than mine, but this works:

```
Measure = 
FORMAT(
    [Pct_measure];
    IF(
        [Pct_measure] >= 0;
         "+0.0%";
         "0.0%" // the negative sign will be carried automatically 
    )
)
```

NB this returns the value of [Pct_measure] as text.